# When is a finitary functor induced by Ind (co)continuous

Tags: ct.category-theory, adjoint-functors, locally-presentable-categories

Let $\mathbf C$ and $\mathbf D$ be small categories. $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathbf C)$ is an accessible category (by definition), and is locally finitely presentable (i.e. cocomplete, or equivalently complete) iff $\mathbf C$ has finite colimits. Let $\mathbf C$ and $\mathbf D$ have finite colimits, and consider a functor $F : \mathbf C \to \mathrm{Ind}(\mathbf D)$. By the universal property of $\mathrm{Ind}$, this extends to a finitary functor $\tilde F : \mathrm{Ind}(\mathbf C) \to \mathrm{Ind}(\mathbf D)$.

In terms of $F$, assuming such a characterisation exists:

1. When is $\tilde F$ continuous? (Equivalently, when does $\tilde F$ have a left adjoint?)
2. When is $\tilde F$ cocontinuous? (Equivalently, when does $\tilde F$ have a right adjoint?)

I imagine (2) should hold when $F$ preserves finite colimits, though I wasn't able to find a reference in *Locally presentable and accessible categories*.

Comment: Your "iff" is not quite correct, I think. You should assume idempotents split.

Comment: @ZhenLin: just to clarify, what would be the corrected statement?

Comment: Assuming idempotents in $\mathcal{C}$ split, $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa (\mathcal{C})$ has colimits if and only if $\mathcal{C}$ has $\kappa$-small colimits.

Comment: If I understand correctly: if $\mathcal C$ has $\kappa$-small colimits, then idempotents in $\mathcal C$ split. So is this to say that $\mathbf{Ind}_\kappa(\mathcal C)$ may be cocomplete even if $\mathcal C$ does *not* have $\kappa$-small colimits, but idempotents in $\mathcal C$ do split?

Comment: No, if we don't know that idempotents in $\mathcal{C}$ split then we cannot conclude that $\mathcal{C}$ has $\kappa$-small colimits even if $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa (\mathcal{C})$ is cocomplete.

Comment: Sorry, I realise I omitted a critical negation in my previous comment. Thank you for your patience! Suppose $\mathbf{Ind}_\kappa(\mathcal C)$ is cocomplete. If idempotents in $\mathcal C$ split, then we know that $\mathcal C$ has $\kappa$-small colimits. However, if idempotents in $\mathcal C$ do not split, then $\mathcal C$ cannot have $\kappa$-small colimits, or otherwise its idempotents would split. Is there a specific example of a small category in which idempotents do not split, but whose $\mathbf{Ind}_\kappa$-completion is cocomplete?

Comment: To clarify where my confusion is coming from, I was basing my original statement of Theorem 5.5(ii) of *A classification of accessible categories* (which I see I must have misunderstood). That paper does not mention idempotents, so I had not appreciated their importance here.

Comment: Ah, perhaps the answer is that, if $\mathbf{Ind}_\kappa(\mathcal C)$ is cocomplete, then there is a category $\mathcal C'$ with $\kappa$-small colimits such that $\mathbf{Ind}_\kappa(\mathcal C) ≃ \mathbf{Ind}_\kappa(\mathcal C')$, but $\mathcal C$ itself may not be.

Comment: That’s right. Every locally $\kappa$-presentable category is equivalent to the category of $\kappa$-ind objects of some $\kappa$-cocomplete category, but that may be a different category from what you start with. (Not too different, in reality: it is the Cauchy completion.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allow me to generalise to $\kappa$-accessible categories for infinite regular cardinals $\kappa$. Your guess for (2) is correct: if $F$ preserves $\kappa$-small colimits then $\tilde{F}$ preserves colimits. The proof is a little bit indirect.

**Proposition.** Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a category and let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small category with $\kappa$-small colimits.  If $\mathcal{I}$ is $\kappa$-small, then the comparison functor
$$\textbf{Ind}_\kappa ([\mathcal{I}, \mathcal{C}]) \to [\mathcal{I}, \textbf{Ind}_\kappa (\mathcal{C})]$$
is fully faithful and essentially surjective on objects.

(The key point is to show that every diagram of shape $\mathcal{I}$ can be written as a $\kappa$-filtered colimit of diagrams of $\kappa$-presentable objects of the same shape $\mathcal{I}$. Actually, the statement of the proposition is equivalent to this fact, and this is what we need for the next step.)

**Proposition.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with $\kappa$-small colimits, let $\mathcal{E}$ be a category with $\kappa$-filtered colimits, let $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{E}$ be a functor, and let $\tilde{F} : \textbf{Ind}_\kappa (\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{E}$ be the extension. Then $\tilde{F}$ preserves colimits if and only if $F$ preserves $\kappa$-small colimits.

(We already know $\tilde{F}$ preserves $\kappa$-filtered colimits, so it is enough to check whether $\tilde{F}$ preserves $\kappa$-small colimits. The "only if" direction is easy. The "if" direction is proved using the previously mentioned decomposition of $\kappa$-small diagrams.)

I don't have a good answer for (1), but perhaps this will be enough for your purposes:

**Proposition.** Let $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ be small categories with $\kappa$-small colimits. A functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ has a left adjoint if and only if $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa (F) : \textbf{Ind}_\kappa (\mathcal{C}) \to \textbf{Ind}_\kappa (\mathcal{D})$ has a left adjoint.

(The "only if" direction is easy: after all, $\textbf{Ind}_\kappa$ is a pseudofunctor so it preserves adjunctions. The "if" direction amounts to saying that the left adjoint of a $\kappa$-accessible functor between locally $\kappa$-presentable categories preserves $\kappa$-presentable objects, which is straightforward to check.)

Comment: Off-topic, but the url listed on your user page is broken. It's good to see you here again, btw!

Comment: Thanks! I updated the link. (Nothing new there though.)

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! Is there reason to believe there may not be a nice characterisation for (1)?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect anything as nice as (2). For example you might consider $\textbf{CRing}^X$ where $X$ is an infinite set. This is a locally finitely presentable category for general reasons, but the terminal object – the limit of the empty diagram! – is not finitely presentable. So one has to do more work to figure out how a finitely accessible functor defined on finitely presentable objects is going to act on the terminal object.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice example. I think simply knowing that there isn't such an elegant characterisation for (1) is enough to answer that part of my question. I had hoped there would be a condition not much more complex than that for (2), but suspected it might not be the case.